# SQL Server trigger to track annual revenue

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms-2012

I have a simple database with 4 tables:

- Customer (cusId)
- Newspaper (papId)
- SubCost (subId)
- Subscription (cusId, papId, subId)

`Newspaper` has a column to track number of subscribers which is updated via a trigger on the `Subscription` table. It also has a column to track annual revenue which should be based on the number of subscribers and the cost associated with the subscription (`subId`).

I am looking for a trigger to track annual revenue. There are 3 subscription types (`subId`) with differing weekly costs and a paper can have more than one type of subscription so it can't just be (`cost * 52 * numSubs`).

Can you help me with this logic?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is not using such a column at all. Instead use a view which computes the result, and index it if necessary

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vTotalSubs
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

SELECT
  n.papid,
  TotalRevenue = SUM(sc.Cost * 52),
  TotalSubscriptions = COUNT_BIG(*)  -- you MUST have this column here if aggregating with an index
FROM dbo.Newspaper n
JOIN dbo.Subscription s ON s.papid = n.papid
JOIN dbo.SubCost sc ON sc.subid = s.subid
GROUP BY
  n.papid;

GO
```

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_vTotalSubs ON vTotalSubs (papid);
```

If you decide to index the view, be aware there are many restrictions to indexed views, in particular:

- Only `INNER JOIN` is allowed, no other join types, no subqueries
- Must schema-bind, and specify schema on all tables.
- If aggregating, you must have `COUNT_BIG(*)`, and the only other aggregation allowed is `SUM`
- Make sure to add the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint when querying, otherwise there may be performance impacts

The server will automatically maintain the index, you do not need to update it.

Comment: I tried this solution and it does successfully create a view that tracks both annual revenue and number of subscribers, but I really would prefer a trigger that updates the annualRev column in the table.

Comment: Such a column would be a denormalization and should generally be avoided. In a database you should only store a piece of information in one place. This method does that, as it is the server that maintains the consistency, whereas using a trigger could potentially leave you open to inconsistency, such as if the trigger were disabled, or someone did a `Bulk Insert` operation without triggers